# WPF XAML two buttons that change webbrowser url on a different window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, webbrowser-control, uri

I cannot seem to get my two buttons on Window2 to successfully change the webbrowser url on my main window.  All I want to do is click button one and go to one address, and click the other button and go to a different address.
I've tried binding without any luck, and I've tried setting the MainWindow webbrowser to a new Uri, but that doesn't work either.  I get an error: 'NullReferenceException was unhandled' "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;



namespace _2CAMS
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window2.xaml
/// </summary>
/// 

public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    MainWindow mw;

    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ShowActivated = true;
        this.MouseLeftButtonDown += delegate { this.DragMove(); };
    }

    private void Button1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }

    private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //this.DragMove();
    }

    private void Image1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.website.com");

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized;

        //App.Current.MainWindow.Hide();
        Window3 win3 = new Window3();
        win3.Show();
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized;
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mw.webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.address1.com"));

    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        mw.webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.address2.com"));
    }

}
}
```

Comment: *That* code gives you an NRE? Which variable is null?

Comment: Not sure, I didn't see anything when looking at the 'View Details...' Or maybe I just don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: [snapshot](http://s42.photobucket.com/user/cheapkid1/media/c_zpsamhxjbwy.png.html)

Comment: You need to hover over each element and determine *what* is null.

Comment: How are you accessing you mainwindow in Window2? Post the more code.

Comment: I've added the rest of my Window2 cs code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow).webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://address1.com"));
```

Does it work, or it throws InvalidCastException?

Comment: That worked, however when in sequence I click button 4 it loads the appropriate page, then when I click button 5 it loads the appropriate page, but with an error.  However the strange thing is when I reverse the sequence and start with button 5 first, then button 4 afterwards and then alternating as many times as I want, it produces no error.  I'm confused.

Comment: This is what [error](http://s42.photobucket.com/user/cheapkid1/media/c_zpsj0gpf2cl.jpg.html) I get.  This is on my MainWindow.cs code.

Comment: After a bit of research I'm still not sure why I get that error, however I was able to just place two separate webbrowsers on my MainWindow and make the buttons 4 & 5 alternate which webbrowser is visible/hidden.  This seems to work without error.  Thanks for all the help guys.

Comment: Isn't  it because you are trying to scroll to invalid position? Anyway, this is another issue. Better ask new question on stackoverflow, you will have better chance to get answer

Comment: Well technically it's not an invalid position because I can switch the source addresses and it works the same way. and the webbrowser window has the same size and position and scroll position.  Beats me.(shoulder shrug)